# Find $(\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty} P_n)$ $\setminus$ $(\bigcap_{k=1}^{\infty} P_n)$. Prove that your expression of this set is correct.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

For any $n$ $\in$ $\mathbb{Z^+}$ let $P_n$ $=$ {$2^{nm}$ | $m$ $\in$ $\mathbb{Z}$}.

Find $(\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty} P_n)$ $\setminus$ $(\bigcap_{k=1}^{\infty} P_n)$. Prove that your expression of this set is correct.

What I've done so far:

$P_1$ $=$ {..., $1/2^3$, $1/2^2$, $1/2$, $1$, $2$, $2^2$, $2^3$,...} $=$ all integer powers of $2$.

$P_2$ $=$ {..., $1/2^6$, $1/2^4$, $1/2^2$, $1$, $2^2$, $2^4$, $2^6$,...} $=$ all integer powers of 4.

$P_3$ $=$ {..., $1/2^9$, $1/2^6$, $1/2^3$, $1$, $2^3$, $2^6$, $2^9$,...} $=$ all integer powers of 8.

Would $(\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty} P_n)$ = the set of all integer powers of $2$ (i.e. $P_1$)? My understanding is that $\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}$ denotes all $x$ s.t. $x$ $\in$ some $P_n$. And since an element is in the indexed intersection if and only if the element is in all of the sets, would $(\bigcap_{k=1}^{\infty} P_n)$ $=$ $1$?

I'm not sure my approach here is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $x \in P_n$ for every $n$. certainly $x=2^{k}$ for some integer $k$. For every positive integer $n$ there exists an integer $m$ such that $2^{k}=2^{nm}$. So $k=nm$ and $n$ divides $k$. Thus every positive integer $n$ divides $k$. This implie $k=0$. Hence the only elmenent of $\bigcap_n P_n $ is $1$. Thus $(\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty} P_n)$ $\setminus$ $(\bigcap_{k=1}^{\infty} P_n)$ consists of all powers of $2$ except $1$.

Comment: Shouldn’t the set be all the powers of 2 except 2^0?

Comment: @Karam Yes, of course! I was careless in the last sentence.